Boot into terminal after upgrading from 22.04 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS
I just upgraded to 24.04, but the boot process stops at Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS tty1 login.
I get the message Ubuntu clean and then:
[FAILED] Failed to start apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles.
[DEPEND] ...
[DEPEND] ...
..
[FAILED] Failed to start snap.docker.nvidia....


[SOLVED] The problem was an incomplete upgrade installation. Relaunch the upgrade solves the problem
